# How to tell if a group of values adheres to a target function

Tags: algorithm, math

I have electronic data readings obtained from a probe. From looking at the data I must tell if the data is ***correct*** . By ***correct*** I mean that the data adheres to the same pattern as a given target function. For instance the X axis values would be time and the Y axis would be tension.

The given target function is provided by a list of correct readings (x,y) values .

I have read about *numerical analysis* and *function approximation* but I wonder if I am on the correct path. Could anyone provide some light on this ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “same pattern”? How is the target function given?

Comment: Are you looking for [goodness of fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit)? ("Measures of goodness of fit summarize the discrepancy between observed values and the values expected under the model in question")

Comment: Sorry for being so vague @svick , I added how the target function is given (by a group of x,y values).

Comment: That sounds like a statistical analysis. Use a statistics package or a numerics/data language (R, Matlab, numpy/pandas,...) There should be something for almost all common platforms.

Comment: Goodness of fit is just what I was looking for @phg, I would gladly accept an answer ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what you trying to find out is called [goodness of fit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit). It basically measures how good the actual data and your assumed model correlate.

There should be tools/libs for this in most languages, and probably specific stuff in statistics/data languages like R or Matlab. Python is widely used for data analysis, too ([pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/), [numpy](https://numpy.org/))

Additionally, there's a SE site for statistics: https://stats.stackexchange.com/